# Sending download counter data to a site

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, download, counter

I want to make a download counter in my app and when you downloaded the image the counter will send the data too a site where I can read the counts, but I know how to make a download counter, but how let I send it data to a site so that the site will display 1 when once downloaded and 2 when twice and so on..

Can somebody please get me on the right way for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a web-server and a database that stores the current count.

You would start with that count at 0.

Then every time that image is requested, you would add one to the counter, render that count onto the image, and send that image off to whatever requested it (the web-server would normally take care of the last one).